# Is Go recursive function call tail-optimized?

Tags: go

See: https://gobyexample.com/recursion

Some languages like Erlang have TCO. Is it the case with Go as well?

Specifically, I mean the main (popular for now) compiler available here: http://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: @Grzegorz: Since there's only one (real/popular/official) compiler really now, the point is moot.

Comment: @Grzegorz: I wrote clearly: REAL, POPULAR, OFFICIAL. Almost nobody is using gcc go compiler. Try to answer the actual question instead of nitpicking on irrelevant tangents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Tail call optimization](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/nOS2FEiIAaM/miAg83qEn-AJ)
>
> There are no such plans for gc (6g, 5g, 8g).
>
> I think it's very unlikely that the language would require it.
>
> Russ

In the unlikely event that this changes, it will be documented in the [Go Release History](http://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html).

Comment: The "useful stack trace" rationale Russ laid out at this link  seems to be very similar to Guido van Rossum's rationale on why CPython VM does not have TCO either.